# Flutter Drift(Moor): concat two columns

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, flutter-moor

I have a [Table](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/advanced_dart_tables/) called `Contracts`:

```dart
class Contracts extends Table {
  TextColumn get firstName => text().named('firstname')();

  TextColumn get lastName => text().named('lastname')();

  // some more columns
}
```

In a [View](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/advanced_dart_tables/#views), I want to concatenate both columns to one like in SQL:

```sql
firstname || ' ' || lastname as name
```

```dart
abstract class Bookings extends View {
  Contracts get c;
  @override
  Query as() => select([
    // firstname || ' ' || lastname as name, // what do I have to do here?
    // more stuff 
  ]).from(c);
}
```

But I can't find any method or class or whatever to do that. And I also didn't find any examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the lib gave me the answer, see:
https://github.com/simolus3/moor/discussions/1691#discussioncomment-2197504

Comment: can you pls help me that how to use 'as' keyword in a join query with drift query syntax? I tried much things but not getting success. ex ``select a.fieldName as "field1",....``